# ASP.Net - How to delete a row using dataset

Tags: asp.net

I need to delete a row from the database. Here's what I've got till now. How to execute the sqlcommand in order to delete the appropriate row

```
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim conSQL As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
        conSQL.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DUSHYANT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Phd;Integrated Security=True"

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("delete from Phd_Student where student_id = '" + sidnolabel.Text + "'", conSQL)


        da.SelectCommand = cmd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need data adapter or data set for this task. You'll only need SqlCommand.

```
    Dim conSQL As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
    conSQL.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DUSHYANT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Phd;Integrated Security=True"
    conSQL.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("delete from Phd_Student where student_id = '" + sidnolabel.Text + "'", conSQL)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

If you are really inclined to use datasets you may use [Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/feh3ed13.aspx) method for deleting. It will mark a record in your dataset as deleted. After this you'll need to call AcceptChanges to apply changes to DB.

Note, that passing arguments using string concatenation is a very bad practice, possibly leading to SQL injections. Use parameters instead.